# PHP PDO Not Locking MySQL Table(s)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to run this command in my PHP script to lock my table:

```
$PDO->exec('LOCK TABLES `tblclients` WRITE');
```

Once I run that script, I attempt to `SELECT` from that table inside MySQL Workbench just to verify the table is actually locked. The `SELECT` runs smoothly, which tells me the table has never actually been locked. Am I right?

If I just run the `LOCK TABLES tblclients WRITE` from inside MySQL Workbench, then attempt to `SELECT` the table does show as LOCKED and prevents the `SELECT` from firing off.

It just doesn't seem to be working when I run that query from my PHP script.

In both cases I'm running locally as the `root` user so I have all privileges.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the query succeeds?  What is the result?  Does PDO throw an exception?

Comment: @ExplosionPills the query `LOCK TABLES tblclients WRITE` is not failing. I get no errors and PDO does not throw any exceptions.

Comment: What is the return value of `exec`?

Comment: Hmmm, it's returning `0`... So I guess for whatever reason, it is failing

Comment: 0 = fail? That's not what [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) says.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Hmm, you're right! I'm still struggling with the reason why I can perform `SELECTS/UPDATES` while my script is still running... I lock the table, run through thousands of lines of `UPDATES` and meanwhile, I can still `SELECT/UPDATE` on that table that SHOULD be locked...

Answer (score 2):

MySQL `LOCK TABLES` is a per-session operation.  If you run something like

```
<?php
$PDO->exec("LOCK TABLES tblclients WRITE");
exit;
?>
```

then the mysql connection from PDO is closed immediately and the lock will be released.  In order to properly test this you may try using two separate connections and select with the one that does not lock *or* `sleep` for a period of time so you can run the query manually.

Comment: My `exec` statement is returning `0` so for some reason it seems to be failing and never actually locking the table

Comment: @FastTrack are you sure that the PDO user has LOCK grants?

Comment: Yes - I just ran `SHOW GRANTS` and it returned `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION`

Comment: @FastTrack - `LOCK TABLES` statements don't alter rows—it will not return anything but zero.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario you're right! I'm still struggling with the reason why I can perform `SELECTS/UPDATES` while my script is still running... I lock the table, run through thousands of lines of `UPDATES` and meanwhile, I can still `SELECT/UPDATE` on that table that SHOULD be locked...